# Why is PHP function file_exist() doesn't return FALSE when passed empty file name?

Tags: magento2.3, php

I have a piece of code shown in the screenshot that should check for the existence of a file. I am not sure why file_exists() doesn't return FALSE in case of non-existing files. I passed an empty string to the `$this->get_custom_js_file_contents('')` but the else block doesn't get the control. Please point out to me what is not right in it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

> Returns TRUE if the **file or directory** specified by filename **exists**;

You shouldn't use the `file_exist()` function to validate the directory path in your case. If you want to secure your script from executing when you pass empty filename just add condition on the beginning.

```
if (empty($js_file_name)) {
    return false;
}
```

Or use `is_file()` function.